# Create responsive User Interface in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, responsive-design, responsive

What is the best way to create an User Interface that is responsive in Java?
For example, I want that buttons resize when I change the size of the window...

Comment: not a bad question, but off-topic for SO...

Comment: You can look here: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/rwd-pj-responsive-web-design-in-plain-java

Comment: I know is kind of off-topic but sometimes this questions are useful to newbies like myself

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), as it is a user friendly and powerful layout manager that makes development of responsive interfaces easy.

This minimal example produces a interface with a single button that automatically resizes to fill the size of the window.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("MigLayout");
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
frame.add(new JButton("Button"), "grow");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Moreover the layour manager is grid based, easy to use and extremely customizable, so I'd recommend it for a wide range of situations.